# Stop timesyncd from polling hard coded Debian timeservers

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, ntp

The **systemd-timesyncd** daemon repeatedly tries to contact the following hard coded (compiled) time servers if neither an NTP server is specified manually nor one received via DHCP:

```
0.debian.pool.ntp.org
1.debian.pool.ntp.org
2.debian.pool.ntp.org
3.debian.pool.ntp.org
```

Since I'm operating behind a corporate proxy, it will never be successful to reach these servers. Is there a way to prevent this senseless polling (without recompilation)?

Comment: Just stop the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't allowed to contact any NTP servers to sync with, then disable the the service that does that:

```
 systemctl stop systemd-timesyncd
 systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
```

The first command will stop the service immediately. The second will prevent it from being restarted on the next boot.

Answer (score 2):

You can (now) [configure timesyncd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/timesyncd.conf.html) to use another NTP server in `/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf`:

```
NTP=your_corporate_internal_time_server
```

Most corporate networks have one of these, especially when blocking ntp traffic.
It is usually something like time.corp_domain.com or ntp.corp_domain.com.